# IE8 CSS Display issues on different windows machines

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I've got an issue with a website rendering differently on different machines with the same setup...

I've tested the site on 6 different machines all running IE8 (8.0.7600) on win7 and get 2 variants of how IE wants to display the site. Some machines put about a 10px margin at the top of the page lowering the whole layout and others don't add this.

All the machines are same spec, same OS, same IE version, all running in same combination of IE8 browser mode and IE8 standards mode.

Has anyone else come across this problem before? - Seems incredibly stupid to display differently on the same setup

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head id="ctl00_Head1">
<title>
    Sign in / Register
</title>
<meta property="fb:page_id" content="199610020055520" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.55" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http:///Images/my/fav-icon.ico" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/Prototype1.6.0.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var submitCount = 0;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/Utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Service/Utils/MasterUtils.ashx?proxy&amp;v=2"></script>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        @import url("css/reset-v1.css");
        @import url("css/my/960-framework.css");
        @import url("css/my/base-v5.css");
        @import url("css/my/question-v1.css");
        @import url("css/my/personalMentor-v1.css");
        @import url("JavaScript/My/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.css"); 
    </style> 
    <!--[if IE 9]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/my/ie9.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/my/ie8.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/my/ie7.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/my/ie6-and-down.css" />
    <![endif]-->


<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 
@import url("/Service/Utils/dynamic-css.ashx"); 
-->
</style><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */ function PageLoad() {  } Event.observe(window, 'load', PageLoad, false); /* ]]> */</script></head>

<body>

    <noscript><p style="border:1px solid #FF0000; color:#FF0000; margin:1em; padding:0.5em; text-align:center;">NOTE: Many features on this website require Javascript and cookies. You can enable both via your browser's preference settings.</p></noscript>

    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Login.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_MainContent_btnLogin')" id="aspnetForm">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEFIELDCOUNT" id="__VIEWSTATEFIELDCOUNT" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE1" id="__VIEWSTATE1" value="cwUIdGV4dEJveDEeBF8hU0ICAmRkAhUPDxYCHwFlZGQCGw8PFgIfAgUHbXlMb2dpbmRkGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYFBRhjdGwwMCRMb2dpblN0YXR1czEkY3RsMDEFGGN0bDAwJExvZ2luU3RhdHVzMSRjdGwwMwUiY3RsMDAkTWFpbkNvbnRlbnQkcmJFeGlzdGluZ01lbWJlcgUdY3RsMDAkTWFpbkNvbnRlbnQkcmJOZXdNZW1iZXIFHWN0bDAwJE1haW5Db250ZW50JHJiTmV3TWVtYmVykV9abJNHuNgL441+VmD4iPEq9Bg=" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=zU9aq3bbkSvgw3OYU-u5XFkq0l4LoCwHFr9S5FOsIgQVsWYiTTdCYCijlA302CHGLHx0sg2&amp;t=634210400612724343" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=Zk81Z4C8G8DXldNoGNf8Z_2GBJ9XiOXkOI4Ay2XZRVzPq7F3j9b2z81RMiPp3nNPN7nzoTMK-pD_jEIu2e2oyFf9pS41&amp;t=634210400612724343" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=0sLRI7n71fW27LNCWM9O6iqOy8v2tNXXti8hupDC0T78K82IErLD8Soi4XyPIWiwFfmJpw2&amp;t=634210400612724343" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
if (typeof(ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) return false;return submitForm();
return true;
}
//]]>
</script>

<div>

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWCwLI7Y+4DgLh8vmTCAL+4L5OAr7C0K8NAu3vp7YPAtqmqyECwfzBkwoC78603ggCzaPcqwwCkZyKvQ8C09GzpwF2P6jZYvvVKVJpSY9a6RmiD4Hm5Q==" />
</div>

    <!--// LOADING TAB SURROUNDING DIV SET TO DISPLAY NONE AS NOT RETURNING LOGIC BREAKS THINGS //-->
    <div style="display:none">
    <div id="loading" class="loadingTab" style="display: none;">Loading...</div>
    </div>




        <div class="container_12">
            <!--// LOGO //-->
            <div class="logo grid_8">
                <a href="/Dashboard/Default.aspx">IMAGE<a>
            </div>

            <!--// SIGN IN/OUT & MY PREFS TABS //-->
            <div class="topRightControls">

                        <div class="grid_2">&nbsp;</div>
                    <a id="ctl00_LoginStatus1" class="grid_2 signInOutTab" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$LoginStatus1$ctl02','')">Sign In</a>

            </div>
            <!--// PRIMARY NAV BAR //-->
            <div class="primaryNav grid_12">
                <ul class="tabNav"><li><a  class="navItemInactive" href="/Community/NewsLatest.aspx" ><span>Community</span></a></li></ul>
            </div>

            <!--// SECONDARY NAV BAR //-->
            <div class="secondaryNav grid_12">
                <div class="nav"><ul class="tabNav"><li><a  class="navItemActive" href="/Login.aspx" title="" ><span>Sign In</span></a></li></ul></div>
                <IMAGE style="float: right; margin-top: 6px;" />
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <!--// OLD SIDEBAR NAV //
            <div class="sideMenuNavigation">

            </div>-->

            <!--// MAIN CONTENT //-->
```

Comment: Does one of the sites happen to be on a local address or IP, and the other on a remote one?

Comment: No, they are both being viewed on the same url wich is a beta testing site but none the less a live served website

Comment: @Devil hmm, in that case you will probably need to show some code. Maybe there are some unwanted characters to the top of your HTML source code?

Comment: If you can provide a URL for us to look at, it would massively help us in figuring out the issue.

Comment: Just added the code, unfortunately the beta testing site is password protected and I can't give that out on here

Comment: This is hard to figure out from code alone. Consider using the DOM inspector (press F12) to find out which element is causing the gap.

Comment: I've tried the DOM inspector, doesn't really let me identify the issue only that it seems the entire body was being forced down in some of the IE8 browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

body {margin-top: 0;}

in an IE8 conditional style sheet fixed it - simple but bloody confusing as to why it would render differently within the same browser - thanks for the help folks